# Why do gen_server examples always define SERVER macro?

Tags: erlang

Why do some examples (and templates in text editor) of `gen_server` have:

```
-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
```

Is there any good reason for it?

This question brought about by [Inaka's guildelines](https://github.com/inaka/erlang_guidelines), where they state the opposite:

> Don't use macros for module or function names

Here is the [code example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inaka/erlang_guidelines/master/src/macro_mod_names.erl) they provide:

```
-module(macro_mod_names).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE). % Oh, god! Why??
-define(TM, another_module).

-export([bad/1, good/1]).

bad(Arg) ->
  Parsed = gen_server:call(?SERVER, {parse, Arg}),
  ?TM:handle(Parsed).

good(Arg) ->
  Parsed = gen_server:call(?MODULE, {parse, Arg}),
  another_module:handle(Parsed).
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does every example (and templates in text editor) of gen_server always have

Searching for "erlang gen_server example", no hits on the first page for me define this macro (and in fact I haven't seen it before). In particular, this includes Erlang documentation's own http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html, "Learn you some Erlang", and the Erlang wikibook.

> Is there any good reason for it?

The reason is clearly to use a more "descriptive" name; whether this is a *good* reason is a question of taste.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.minostro.com/programming-languages/erlang/2015/06/13/rebar-templates.html

Comment: Well, I expected there are some examples or you wouldn't have asked this question. My point was that this is far from "always" and not used in the most widely used sources. So, as I said, just a matter of taste.

Comment: The [emacs skeletons provided with Erlang/OTP](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/tools/emacs/erlang-skels.el) all contain, unfortunately IMO, the `SERVER` macro.

Comment: Also, the Erlang plugin for Intellij includes the SERVER define when generating a gen_server skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good practice to use `-define` to define and document relevant variables for the module. This is especially true for variables that get used at different places in the module and you want to make it configurable.

Actually, I think your question tackles this at the wrong side: the `gen_server` name is a module-wide configurable variable (and hence it is best practice to define it), and for the sake of simplicity it became common practice to choose the server name equal to the module name: `gen_server`s name is normally registered so you can send messages to it. Since the name is a critical variable here (and there might even be cases when you would like to change it), it is normally `-defined`ed.

I also think that the guidelines you quotes are speaking about a different use-case for macros.

Comment: But they specifically mention the _SERVER_ macro in the guidelines.